Hoe to use Fancy C or C collection
I would like to create a formula using the following symbol .
As far as I understand, it is called Fancy C or C Collection.
I believe the option to include it in LaTeX (Overleaf) is \mathcal{C} or \mathfrak{C}.
My code is:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
% % % CP ==========================
%\newcommand{\CP}[1]{\ignorespaces}
%\newcommand{\ie}{\textit{i.e.}}
%\newcommand{\eg}{\textit{e.g.}}
%\newcommand{\wrt}{\textit{w.r.t.\ }}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
% % % =============================

\usepackage{authblk}
\providecommand{\keywords}[1]{\textbf{\textit{Keywords:}} #1}
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
$\mathfrak{C}$
\end{document}

when inserting the above character I get errors. How can I create this character?
The error I get:
Undefined control sequence.


You need $\mathfrak{C}$ (in math mode). Regardless, your code doesn't show your use that is causing the problem.

Thanks @Werner, but I still get errors. Could you provide the necessary packages or specify what else I need to add to my code?

Add \usepackage{amssymb} to your preamble, then it should work. Just like is done here How do you make this symbol in math mode? (possible duplicate).

Works like a magic, Thanks!

For future reference, the error starts with that message, but is also the next 9 lines, ending with "and I'll forget about whatever was undefined."
